# Why my VS Code is laggy and mouse is flickering?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

When I use VS Code to develop angular project(for work), the mouse is flickering and IDE is very stubborn.

And I closed the IDE then open it again. Everything is fine, after several minutes, disaster is coming again~!

But when I switch to another project(angular or something else), the disaster disappears. And I switch to work project, I guess you can predict what is happening...

I delete the configuration of VS Code. It'didn't work.

And my workmates never meet my situation.(They using same project)

It's killing me...What should I do?

Comment: Reinstall, check your activity log/task manager, etc.

Comment: Did you try disabling all your extensions? If you still have the same issue, try disabling GPU acceleration when launching VS Code by adding the Electron `--disable-gpu` command line switch.

Answer (score 0):

there's a issue about that on vscode repo
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146993